# how to get images to collectionViewCells from Gallery?

Tags: ios

Hi i can getting the image from gallery but which is not display into collection view.i have written code like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

picker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
self.collectionView.delegate = self;
self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
[self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CELL"];

}
- (IBAction)galleryClicked:(id)sender
{

NSLog(@"GalleryClicked");

picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
picker.delegate = self;
[picker setAllowsEditing:YES];
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];

}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info

{
inputImage= info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
NSLog(@"inputImage is :%@",inputImage);
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 100;
}

- (MyCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

MyCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CELL" forIndexPath:indexPath];   
UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
UILabel *descLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:110];
self.recipeImageView.image = inputImage;    
return cell;
}
```

please anybody suggest me how to to do this .help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `self.recipeImageView.image = inputImage;` to `recipeImageView.image = inputImage;`.

Comment: yes its working ...thankq soo much Dennis but i want get one image which should be saved in collectionviewCell like if i get  image from gallery that should be saved in collectionViewCell1 if get next one that should be saved in collection view Cell2 etc..

Comment: could u  please suggest me how to do this Dennis

Comment: Simply use the `indexPath` parameter in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method. The `indexPath.row` property will give you the row of the cell you are currently building. You can use this value to get the right image to display. E.g. if you have an `NSArray` which holds all the images you selected from the gallery, you can do  `recipeImageView.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` to assign the image at the specific index.

Comment: thankq for replying me .but here every time want to get one image from gallery that

Comment: should be saved in collectonViewCell in order..so

Comment: can we store one image in array

Comment: i am asking about how to save images in oderwise in uiCollectionview

Comment: Whenever the user selects a photo from the gallery, add it to the `imageArray` which you hold in your `UIViewController`. You also need to implement the `collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:` method, and return the number of images you currently have: `return [imageArray count];`. After that, you need to call `[collectionView reloadData];` to update the `UICollectionView`.

Comment: dennis images are not getting into the collection view

Comment: -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info

{
    
inputImage= info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    imagesArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:inputImage, nil];
}

Comment: - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    
    return [imagesArray count];
  
    
}

Comment: - (MyCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ recipeImageView.image =[imagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    
    NSLog(@"recipeImageView is:%@",recipeImageView.image);
  
    [collectionView reloadData]; return cell;
    
}

Comment: suggest me if i did any mistake

Comment: You wrote `imagesArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:inputImage, nil];`. This will overwrite the array every time. You need to add the image instead: `[imagesArray addObject:inputImage];`. Make sure that you initialize the array before (e.g. in `viewDidLoad`) by calling `imagesArray = [NSMutableArray array];`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72755/discussion-between-vani-lucky-and-dennis).

Comment: i implemented like that ..every time array size increases but images are not getting into collectionView Dennis
i can choose the image from gallery but thats not display into CollectionView
getting blank view
could u please suggest me how to resolve this

Comment: collectinviewCell are not disply

Comment: Not sure what exactly the problem might be, but I suggest you start a new question for it, as the original question was answered. Pls make sure to add your current source code as well.

Comment: k thankq but in i took collectionView and gave datasourse and delegate methods

Comment: but why i don't knew to does nt display UICollacetionViewCells in UI

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad
{
 imagesArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    
    [self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CELL"];
    }

Comment: -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info

{
    
inputImage= info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
     [imagesArray addObject:inputImage]; [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    
}

Comment: -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView;
{
    
 
    return 1;
    
}


- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    
    return [imagesArray count];
    
}

Comment: - (MyCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    
    
MyCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CELL" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    
    if(!cell)
    {
        cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CELL"forIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    
  recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
     recipeImageView.image =[imagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   [collectionView reloadData];

    return cell;
    
}